# How to Add migration at run time via code

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am changing Db-context at rum time of behalf of condition with other db connection so problem is this we not able to how to make database at run time if database not exist via code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {  
           services.AddDbContext<TenantsDbContext>(options =>              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))

            services.AddDbContext<MultitenantDbContext>();           

            // for dependency.
            services.AddTransient<ITenantProvider, DatabaseTenantProvider>();
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MultitenantDbContext>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

and change db connection at run time.

```
public MultitenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<MultitenantDbContext> options,
                                    ITenantProvider tenantProvider) : base(options)
        {
            _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;         
            _connectionString = @"Server=Test\SQL2017;Database=" + _tenantProvider.GetTenantId() + ";User ID=sa;Password=123;";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just `dbContext.Migrate();`
Also, you can use `dbContext.EnsureCreated();`. It will check if database exists, and will migrate if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
    {
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var appDb = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<MultitenantDbContext>();

        appDb.Database.Migrate();
    }

}
```

From specification `Migrate()`:

> Note that this API is mutually exclusive with
>   DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated(). EnsureCreated does not use
>   migrations to create the database and therefore the database that is
>   created cannot be later updated using migrations.

So `appDb.Database.Migrate();` is totally enough. It will create database if not exist, and will run every pending migrations.